# Para que serve o Fauxgap.js

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, mobile

tudo bem?

Após ver alguns artigos sobre dev mobile, muito se falou em um arquivo facilitador para emulação chamado fauxgap.js

O que exatamente ele faz? Emula o cordova e phonegap js no navegador? Eu não entendi muito bem. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a página no site da Intel,

> This script fulfills the entire Apache Cordova* (PhoneGap) API and is configurable. It can be used with pages that are being tested with Preview or for unit testing.

Em tradução livre:

> Este script oferece a API Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) e é configurável. Ele pode ser usado com páginas que estão sendo testadas com a pré-visualização ou para testes de unidade.

Fonte:
[Fauxgap Javascript](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fauxgapjs)